# Error on installing Rattle in Ubuntu

Tags: r, ubuntu

I'm trying to install Rattle in Ubuntu 14.04, but I'm getting this error:

```
Error in loadNamespace(name) : there is no package called ‘RGtk2’
```

But when I try to install RGtk2 I get this:

```
configure: error: GTK version 2.8.0 required
ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘RGtk2’
```

When I try to install libgtk2.0-dev

with

```
sudo apt-get install libgtk2.0-dev
```

I get:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libgtk2.0-dev : Depends: libgtk2.0-0 (= 2.24.23-0ubuntu1) but 2.24.23-0ubuntu1.1 is to be installed
                 Depends: libglib2.0-dev (>= 2.27.3) but it is not going to be installed
                 Depends: libgdk-pixbuf2.0-dev (>= 2.21.0) but it is not going to be installed
                 Depends: libpango1.0-dev (>= 1.20) but it is not going to be installed
                 Depends: libatk1.0-dev (>= 1.29.2) but it is not going to be installed
                 Depends: libcairo2-dev (>= 1.6.4-6.1) but it is not going to be installed
```

And when I try

```
sudo apt-get install libgtk2.0
```

I get:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libgtk2.0-0-dbg : Depends: libgtk2.0-0 (= 2.24.23-0ubuntu1) but 2.24.23-0ubuntu1.1 is to be installed
 libgtk2.0-dev : Depends: libgtk2.0-0 (= 2.24.23-0ubuntu1) but 2.24.23-0ubuntu1.1 is to be installed
                 Depends: libglib2.0-dev (>= 2.27.3) but it is not going to be installed
                 Depends: libgdk-pixbuf2.0-dev (>= 2.21.0) but it is not going to be installed
                 Depends: libpango1.0-dev (>= 1.20) but it is not going to be installed
                 Depends: libatk1.0-dev (>= 1.29.2) but it is not going to be installed
                 Depends: libcairo2-dev (>= 1.6.4-6.1) but it is not going to be installed
```

Comment: Did you install something like `libgtk2.0-dev`?

Comment: no I didn't install. How can I install it?

Comment: `sudo apt-get install libgtk2.0-dev`

Comment: I tried but I get errors on dependency of pachages. I edited my question, take a look

Comment: I think you could search by yourself on Internet. You need to do first `apt-get update` to refresh the list of available packages.

Comment: `sudo apt-get install libgtk2.0-dev` works with Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: for me both `libgtk2.0` and `libgtk2.0-dev` work fine in Mint 18.3

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Acording to http://rattle.togaware.com/rattle-install-troubleshooting.html

the source of Rattle if you have that problem in ubuntu, it is solved by doing this

```
wajig install libgtk2.0-dev
```

I did it and it worked, your computer may ask you to install wajig by doing

```
sudo apt-get install wajig
```

go ahead and do it.

Comment: I used this to install `clusterfly` package in `R 3.2.2` on `Ubuntu 16.04`  which drew the same error message. Besides `libgtk2.0-dev` I also had to install `ggobi` manually with `sudo apt-get install ggobi` to make `clusterfly` run. Now everything installed correctly thanks to your code.